# How do i hide the auto-generated custom field that's created when update_post_meta() is called?

Tags: metabox

I've added a custom textarea for the create/edit post admin page. I did so using the add_meta_box() function. The problem is that the add_meta_box() callback function (which saves the data input into the textarea) calls the update_post_meta(). update_post_meta() then adds a custom field within the custom field section. So you essential end up with two textareas for the same field! The one you've created and the auto generated one!

Is there a way to remove the auto generated custom field?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

If the meta field starts with an underscore, [it will be hidden in the interface](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L2375) by adding the class `hidden` to the `<tr>` element. You could also apply this class by yourself using Javascript, the `<tr>` element has an id of `meta-{$custom_field_id}`.

Comment: Hi Jan. Thanks for the reply. Prefixing the name with and underscore hides the auto generated custom field AND the manually added meta box! So that's no good really.